# the Rails Way of associating images with products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've got two models, `Product` and `Image`. `Product` has two columns: `name` and `description`.`Image` also has two columns: `path` (i.e., foobar.jpg) and `description` (for captions and `alt` info). Most images depict multiple products and there are multiple images of each product. Each product has its own page that will feature a gallery of all relevant images.

Originally I thought the best way to solve this would be a HABTM association - but I've since read (in *The Rails 3 Way*) that those are now frowned upon in favor of the `has_many :through` association. But creating a third model seems silly here.

Another solution I've considered is to, on each product page, search the `Image` `description` column for the `Product` `:name`. But this doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

What's the Rails Way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `has_many :through` would be the rails way, but the underlying data structure can still be the same. I would model the relationships this way:

```
class Product
  has_many :product_images
  has_many :images, :through => :product_images
end

class ProductImage
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :image
end

class Image
  has_many :product_images
  has_many :products, :through => :product_images
end
```

So in other words the only difference between HABTM and `has_many :through` is the relationship declarations and the extra model. Yes, the extra model may seem like overkill, but it doesn't detract from the maintainability of the code.